# Android AWS S3 security alert

Tags: android, amazon-s3

I published android apps 2 days ago. The apps is working well what I think. But, now I get a message from google-play. Like this.

> Security alert
>
> Your Amazon Web Services credentials may be exposed.
>   This exposure of your credentials could lead to unauthorized access to
>   your AWS account, which may include associated excessive charges, and
>   potentially unauthorized access to your data and your users' data.

My apps use S3 connection for direct upload. I referred follow page "http://java.awsblog.com/post/Tx2Q9SGR6OKSVYX/Amazon-S3-TransferManager" for implementing upload function.

And also I make instance of TransferManager like this.

> TransferManager tx = new TransferManager(new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY_ID, SECRET_KEY));

What is my mistake? Is it bed at using keys directly? If yes, what can I do to avoid this alert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using the Java server libraries which assume only a few machines will be connecting to your S3 account. You should probably be looking at Amazon's mobile SDK:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/setup.html

Comment: I re-checked library files. But, I use correct library, aws-android-sdk-2.1.5.

Comment: And you are using Cognito like their sample: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/S3_TransferManager/src/com/amazonaws/demo/s3_transfer_manager?

Comment: Thanks @Morrison Chang. I solve this problem using your suggestion, Cognito. Hmm... Our company should bill more money to Amazon T_T.

Comment: Found the TransferManager blog post which uses access_key,secret_key. If you used the 'master' keys in the app that could be the problem. See: http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx1P6IGLLZ935I4/What-to-Do-If-You-Inadvertently-Expose-an-AWS-Access-Key if its appropriate.